# import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator" vs. import Vue from "vue"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, decorator, javascript-decorators

What's the difference and use cases between importing `Vue` from `vue-property-decorator` and `vue`? What I understood I need to import `Vue` from `vue-property-decorator` always when defining a custom component with a `@Component` decorator, but are there any unexpected/different things/scenarios related to the `Vue`'s core which I should be aware when doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that there is no difference according to [sources](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/master/src/vue-property-decorator.ts#L12) of `vue-property-decorator`.

`vue-property-decorator` just does the following:

```
import Vue, { PropOptions, WatchOptions } from 'vue'
// ...
export { Component, Vue, mixins as Mixins }
```

Possible that it is done to reduce number of imports in your code:

```
import {Vue, Smth1, Smth2}` from 'vue-property-decorator';
```

vs

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {Smth1, Smth2} from 'vue-property-decorator';
```

Comment: Clear answer and must be accepted. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a very simple module named 'some-module', in it you have:

```
var foo = 'bar';
export default foo;
export function helloWorld () { ... };
```

When you do:

```
import something from 'some-module';
```

you are only importing the default export of 'some-module'. In this case, it is the string foo. The default export can be anything, object, function, etc.

When you do:

```
import {helloWorld} from 'some-module';
```

You are specifically importing a member of 'some-module' named 'helloWorld' and not the default export. In this case, it is the function 'helloWorld'.

If you had done:

```
import {something} from 'some-module';
```

The 'something' would be 'undefined' since there is no export for with that name.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: thank you for the contribution, but the question was what's the difference between importing `Vue` from these 2 specific modules and how it might influence on my project. The question was not about techniques how to import a JavaScript module.